# Jena Custom Rules using Built-ins

Tags: jena, jena-rules

I am currently messing around with Jena trying to create rules to add to my generic reasoner. I created the following simple rule:

```
[rule1: (?x ?rdf:type ?y),(?y rdfs:subClassOf ?z)-> (?x rdfs:type ?z)]
```

This works fine, and fires correctly, giving me everything I expect. After I did this I wanted to assign a timestamp to `?x`, so that I'd know when the conclusion was come to, I wanted to used the [`Now`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/Now.html) builtin as follows.

```
[rule1: (?x ?rdf:type ?y),(?y rdfs:subClassOf ?z),now(?x)-> (?x rdfs:type ?z)]
```

This unfortunately does not work, it does nor throw an error, it just does not seem to bind any time value to `?x` and also it seems to prevent the rule from being fired correctly as in the first case. The ontology I am using is below. Any ideas?

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="livingthing"></owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="Human">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="livingthing"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="john">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="Human"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/Now.html), `Now` will “Bind the first arg to the current date time in the current locale and timezone.”  I haven't tried using `Now`, but I'd expect that "the current date time in the current locale and timezone" is a some sort of RDF literal (perhaps a date or datetime)?  Literals cannot be the subjects of triples in RDF.  For the rule

```
[rule1: (?x ?rdf:type ?y),(?y rdfs:subClassOf ?z),now(?x) -> (?x rdfs:type ?z)]
```

to match in the graph, the variable `?x` will be bound to the date literal, say, `"2013-05-24"` (but as I mentioned, I don't know exactly what `Now` will produce) but there cannot be any matches for `(?x rdf:type ?y)` because these would have the form `"2013-05-24" rdf:type ?y` and there cannot be triples of that form.  This means that the rule cannot fire.

If you want to add a timestamp to something, you probably want an [n-ary relation](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/), so that you're actually representing (or representing, in addition to `?x rdf:type ?z`) a relation *inferredSubclassRule(?super,?sub,?time )*, which can be represented in RDF by a blank node like:

```
[] a :inferredSubclassRule ;
   :hasSuperClass ?super ;
   :hasSubClass ?sub ;
   :hasTimestamp ?time .
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. n-ary relations seem to be what I am looking for.